# Comments are returning markdown.

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

Look at the output of the following:

> http://api.askubuntu.com/1.0/questions/12218?comments=true

**Output:**

```
{
    "comment_id": 12713,
    "creation_date": 1289269467,
    "owner": {
        "user_id": 41,
        "user_type": "moderator",
        "display_name": "Marco Ceppi",
        "reputation": 5325,
        "email_hash": "c127c8150f8052e4b89d66f42b99be56"
    },
    "post_id": 12218,
    "post_type": "question",
    "score": 0,
    "body": "Possible Duplicate: ['Installing' Applications, where to put folders?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2053/installing-applications-where-to-put-folders)"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.  Bug (typo really) introduced while tuning up some routes.

Comment: Great! _` ` ` ` ` `_